# Send Case Auto Response Email To Associated Person Account

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, case-auto-response

This question related to an earlier question I posted ([Case Auto Response From Case Created By Controller Class: How To Debug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124262/case-auto-response-from-case-created-by-controller-class-how-to-debug/124282#124282)) but is of a different flavour.

In my previous question I queried how I can initiate an auto response email from a case created via code. I now what to clarify, in relation to the Auto Response can I send it to the associated Person Account instead of Contact.  I do not have the contact field populated but will have an associated Person Account

I know I can send an Email Alert via a Workflow Rule by using an Email field which I populate via a field update to get the email address of the associated Person Account but I would like to use the standard Case Auto Response functionality if at all possible for this scenario as 1) it attached the email activity against the case, and 2) allows a reply to the email to be associated to the case.

I note on the following link it details sending an auto response to an account and the person who submitted a Web To Lead case.  I'm not using Web-To-Lead as it did not meet all out leads. When it states "Person" who submitted a lead, could this refer to a person account?

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=rules_differences_auto_workflow.htm&language=en_US

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SFDC have confirmed in a case that this cannot be done.